# write a function in python PUSH(L,num) to insert value in queue

Tags: python

write a function in python PUSH(L,num) to insert value in queue, where L is a Queue implemented by a list of numbers.
Is any program is required ?  or only function to be written

Comment: by insert you mean first or last

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on if you want your queue to be LIFO (last in, first out) or FIFO (first in, first out) you can use `insert` and `pop` to do this.

```
def push(L, num):
    L.insert(0, num)

def pop(L):
    num = L.pop(0)  # LIFO behavior, or L.pop() for FIFO behavior
    return num
```

Examples

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> push(l, 4)
>>> l
[4, 1, 2, 3]
>>> pop(l)
4
>>> l
[1, 2, 3]
```